# Docker compose - run shell and application inside shell

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose for running my application in dev. environment.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      target: base
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true 
    volumes:
     - ./src:/src
    command: node src/main/server/index.js
```

Composer is starting container and I can see logs output from node application. When I press `CTR-C` - container is stopped and my application is stopped as well.

I would like to have my application to be stopped when I press `CTRL-C` instead of whole container.

The same behavior when running an app within Windows CMD or Linux shell. For example, to restart an app - press `CTRL-C`, repeat startup command (`node src/main/server/index.js` by pressing top arrow key), and press enter.

I was thinking I could use something like this, but it does not work.

```
command: bash -c "node src/main/server/index.js
```

I know I can use command below to achieve expected behavior:

- `docker-compose up -d` (to start in detached mode)
- `docker-compose   exec web bash` (run interactive shell)
- `node src/main/server/index.js` (start node manually)

But maybe there is a way to start bash interactive bash and run an application in bash using singe command `docker-compose up` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker runs a main process in its containers, as such, stopping the main process will also stop the container.

I will attempt to answer your question, but I don't think that you should work like that in a Dev environment.

Answering your question, you can "trap" the container in a main process, then just bash into the container and perform the app start.

In order to trap the container, just change the docker-compose `command` to:

```
command: while true; do sleep 1; done;
```

To get into an interactive bash in the container:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> bash
```

And then you can start or stop the node app.

It seems that the problem you are facing is a container taking a lot to start, you should probably reorder your Dockerfile to prevent it from redownloading all dependencies (or other long process) every time a file changes.

You should place your `COPY` command after all commands that should persist from across builds, and take advantage of docker's image layering.

If you need a "hot reload" feature, you can research Webpack hot reloading.
You would need to bind your host volume to the container's work directory in order to let webpack properly watch the files and reload the app.

Comment: Well it's not about rebuilding. What if my compose contain more than node application? It could be an application, database, cache whatever. I don't want to restart them all when I need to restart only single service. And I dpn't use COPY command, I'm injecting volume instead. If I use COPY I will have to rebuild image.

Comment: If you use COPY, place it at the end of the Dockerfile, so that you don't have to rebuild the whole image, only the last layers.
But again, ideally, in a dev environment, you need to make use of the hot reload features.
EDIT: If you start a docker-compose file with -d (detached) and --build, starting it up again won't restart the other services, it will only rebuild your application.

Comment: As i mentioned i'm not using copy at all

Comment: I know you are not, but in a prod environment, you should. Mapping your entire host directory to the container is a security issue. My opinion is that you are trying to fix a problem (container taking a long time to restart) through unconventional methods (trapping containers with another main process). I provided two methods, either using a file watcher utility, or properly ordering Dockerfile commands, if possible.